# Line modification with sed

Tags: sed

When I write in the terminal this line:

```
echo /site/cdlinux/iso/v0.5/cdlinux-maly-0.5.8.iso | sed "s#.*/##"
```

I get this output:

```
cdlinux-maly-0.5.8.iso
```

What do these particular characters (# . * /) mean in this situation?

Comment: Rather than give 5th 'close as too broad' vote, I removed 'too broad' part.  the specific part has what appears to be a good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed "s#.*/##"`

`#` is treated as `sed` command sections separator

`.*/` - a pattern that will match all characters till encountering the last `/`(including) within the input string, i.e. `/site/cdlinux/iso/v0.5/`

`##` - empty string between two section separators is the replacement part(all matched characters will be replaced with empty string)

---

> The syntax of the ***s*** command is ‘`s/regexp/replacement/flags`’.
>  
>   Its basic concept is simple: the s command attempts to match the pattern
>   space against the supplied regular expression *regexp*; if the match
>   is successful, then that portion of the pattern space which was
>   matched is replaced with *replacement*.